# GPU Computation AMD

Tags: gpu

I'm new to this forum even though it has helped me a lot over the last few months. I'm working on hypergeometric functions and want to use my GPU as support. I have a Radeon R9 390, but I can't get it to work with Mathematica.

I am working with Mathematica 11.2, Windows 7, and the driver of my graphics cards says the OpenCL API Version is 2.0, yet

```
OpenCLQ[]
```

returns "False". 
Does anyone have suggestions what I might try?

Comment: "I'm working on hypergeometric functions"... I have my doubts that your graphics card would help at all. What exavtly are you trying to do with it?

Comment: For the moment I am just trying to evaluate them over a broad corridor to save the values in a table to test a few things. I found a paper where hypergeometric functions are evaluated on a GPU, so I had/have hopes it would speed up the parallelization.

Comment: I did not say that it were impossible. It would just be painful to implement. You would have to write you own OpenCL-routines for the hypergeometric functions because _Mathematica's_ routines cannot be called from the GPU. It is probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Moreover, it sounds like you are about to create a lot of data on the GPU in order to play around with it? The latter is also cumbersome to do on the GPU; and running data analysis on the CPU would require you to move the data from the GPU to the CPU. Moving the data would probably take _much more time_ (I am talking about 1 to 2 orders of magnitude) that the time you saved by running the computations on the GPU.

Comment: I am also under the impression that you might need high accuracy results. GPUs are _limited_ to machine precision you definitely, you don't want to implement your own extended precision routines for a GPU.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the input! I'm curious to see how it plays out. It was simply a thought that popped into my mind that maybe my GPU could be useful. My plan was to create once a big table of function values and then use those repeatedly on the CPU.
For now it is just a tool to improve integration routines etc., therefore at the moment high accuracy is not needed.
I value your input, but would you have by chance also any idea regarding my "getting started"-issue? :)

Comment: Sorry, Alex, I am afraid, I cannot help you. I gave up GPU programming a long time ago, because it turned out to be not really useful for my everyday work.